# What's a clean way to have a conditional container in handlebars?

Tags: handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

When there is a link present, we want something like this HTML:

`<a href="{{url}}" title="{{title}}" target="_blank"><img src="{{src}}"></img></a>`

When there is no link present, we want something like this HTML:

`<img src="{{src}}"></img>`

Is there a clean way to do this? I consider the following solution bad, because it's dangerous to have to separately remember to open and close the `<a>` tag:

```
{{#if url}}<a href="{{url}}" title="{{title}}" target="_blank">{{/if}}
  <img src="{{src}}">
{{#if url}}</a>{{/if}}
```

I considered using a block helper, but can't think of how to do so without adding more complexity. Maybe something like:

`{{#linkWrap url}}<img src="{{src}}">{{/linkWrap}}`

But then it's hard to see how we set the `title` and `target` and everything gets awkward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are on the right track, but I would recommend using a Handlebars [*Partial Block*](http://handlebarsjs.com/partials.html#partial-block) instead of a Block Helper. This will allow to pass one piece of template (the block) to another piece of template by which it will be wrapped (the partial).

Handlebars provides us with `{{> @partial-block }}` as a way to render a block of template *within* a partial. We can use this to create our "linkWrap" partial:

```
{{#if link}}
    <a href="{{link.url}}" target="{{link.target}}" title="{{link.title}}">
        {{> @partial-block}}
    </a>
{{else}}
    {{> @partial-block}}
{{/if}}
```

This gives us a clean and simple partial that will allow us to wrap *any* section of our template with a link as long as we have a `link` object to pass to our partial. Note that I have opted to use an object to represent the link so that I can pass a single parameter to the partial instead of passing the `url`, `title`, etc. properties individually.

For anywhere we wish to render a link around some markup in our template, we can do so in the following way:

```
{{#> linkWrap link=link}}
    <img src="{{image.src}}">
{{/linkWrap}}
```

If the `link` object is `null` or `undefined`, the img element will be rendered without a parent anchor element.

I have created a supplementary [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/dunn1e28/) for reference.

Comment: I'm so glad I found this answer, I've been periodically scanning documentation for something like this for a few days now.